# I can't assign the value of a geometry point to a variable

Tags: c++, geometry, ros

I was trying to assign the value of a geometry point (it has x,y,z. All of them are float64. If you want to check it: http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Point.html ) to a float64 variable. But when I compile the code the next error appears:

> error: request for member ‘data’ in ‘msg.nav_msgs::Odometry_std::allocator<void >::pose.geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovariance_std::allocator<void >::pose.geometry_msgs::Pose_std::allocator<void >::position.geometry_msgs::Point_std::allocator<void >::y’, which is of non-class type ‘const _y_type {aka const double}’

> y = (msg.pose.pose.position.y).data;

And the code is the following:

```
#include <geometry_msgs/Point.h>
#include <std_msgs/Float64.h>

//Creo la variable con la informacion a publicar
std_msgs::Float64 y;

void controlMensajeRecibido(const geometry_msgs::Point& msg)
{
  y = msg.y;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

//inicio comunicacion con sistema ROS
ros::init(argc, argv, "coordenadas");
ros::NodeHandle nh;

//Me suscribo al t
ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("/ardrone/odometry/pose/pose/position", 1000, &controlMensajeRecibido);


//creamos un objeto publicador
ros::Publisher pub =nh.advertise<std_msgs::Float64>("/pid_y/state", 1000);  


pub.publish(y); //publico

//cedemos control a ROS
ros::spin();
}
```

I don't know why it doesn't let me do it if the variable is the correct type.
If anyone can help me it'll be amazing.
Thank u

Comment: The line mentioned in your error message, `y = (msg.pose.pose.position.y).data;`, does not appear in your code. You have not provided code that reproduces your error. It might be that you have simplified your code (which would be good), but in that case, please update your error message to reflect the code that is in the question.

Comment: The problem is not the variable `y` but the expression `msg.pose.pose.position.y`, which is a `const double` and thus does not have a `data` member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std_msgs::Float64` has a field "`data`" of type `float64`. Type of `std_msgs::Float64`  is not equal to field "`y`" of type `float64` in  `geometry_msgs::Point`.

```
void controlMensajeRecibido(const geometry_msgs::Point& msg)
{
  y.data = msg.y;
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank u!!